# cd_dynamic_conf with various domains

Tags: 2013, dxa

I have two different domains configured in the cd_dynamic_conf file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration Version="7.1"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="schemas/cd_dynamic_conf.xsd">
    <URLMappings>
        <StaticMappings>
            <Publications>
                <Publication Id="32">
                    <Host Protocol="http" Domain="test-holidays.com” Port="" Path="es" />
                </Publication>
                <Publication Id="33">
                    <Host Protocol="http" Domain=” test-holidays.com" Port="" Path="en" />
                </Publication>
                <Publication Id="41">
                    <Host Protocol="http" Domain="test-vacaciones.com" Port="" Path="/" />
                </Publication>              
            </Publications>
        </StaticMappings>
        <StorageMapping IdentifyPublicationByProperty="publicationUrl"/>
    </URLMappings>
    <TCDLEngine>
        <Properties>
        </Properties>
    </TCDLEngine>
</Configuration>
```

When I check the log:

```
2016-01-25 18:41:14,596 DEBUG [com.tridion.dynamiccontent.publication.resolver.DomainOptionMatcher] (default task-2) The Domain extracted from the url is: [test-vacaciones.com]
2016-01-25 18:41:14,596 DEBUG [com.tridion.dynamiccontent.publication.resolver.DomainOptionMatcher] (default task-2) The mapped Domain is: [test-holidays.com]
2016-01-25 18:41:14,598 DEBUG [com.tridion.dynamiccontent.publication.resolver.DomainOptionMatcher] (default task-2) Mapped Domain DOES NOT match with the url. Mapped Domain is [test-holidays.com] and extracted Domain is [test-vacaciones.com].
2016-01-25 18:41:14,598 DEBUG [com.tridion.dynamiccontent.publication.resolver.DomainOptionMatcher] (default task-2) The calculated weight is [0].
2016-01-25 18:41:14,598 DEBUG [com.tridion.dynamiccontent.publication.resolver.PortOptionMatcher] (default task-2) The Port extracted from the url is: []
2016-01-25 18:41:14,598 DEBUG [com.tridion.dynamiccontent.publication.resolver.PortOptionMatcher] (default task-2) The mapped Port is: []
2016-01-25 18:41:14,598 DEBUG [com.tridion.dynamiccontent.publication.resolver.PortOptionMatcher] (default task-2) The Ports match without port.
2016-01-25 18:41:14,598 DEBUG [com.tridion.dynamiccontent.publication.resolver.PortOptionMatcher] (default task-2) The calculated weight is [1000].
2016-01-25 18:41:14,599 DEBUG [com.tridion.dynamiccontent.publication.resolver.PathOptionMatcher] (default task-2) The Path extracted from the url is: [/index.html]
2016-01-25 18:41:14,599 DEBUG [com.tridion.dynamiccontent.publication.resolver.PathOptionMatcher] (default task-2) The mapped Path is: [es].
2016-01-25 18:41:14,599 DEBUG [com.tridion.dynamiccontent.publication.resolver.PathOptionMatcher] (default task-2) Removed slashs from the path. New path is [es]
2016-01-25 18:41:14,599 DEBUG [com.tridion.dynamiccontent.publication.resolver.PathOptionMatcher] (default task-2) Removed slashs from the path. New path is [index.html]
2016-01-25 18:41:14,599 DEBUG [com.tridion.dynamiccontent.publication.resolver.PathOptionMatcher] (default task-2) Number of chain found at beginning of the path: [0]
2016-01-25 18:41:14,599 DEBUG [com.tridion.dynamiccontent.publication.resolver.PathOptionMatcher] (default task-2) The Path DOES NOT match. Mapped path is [es] and extracted path is
```

Why the domain test-vacaciones.com is not found?

Comment: If this is a direct copy/paste from your cd_dynamic_conf, the quote before test-holidays.com (publication 33) is one of those "smart quotes" from office/outlook, and it will break your xml. Replace it with a regular quote.

Comment: Are you sure that you have the same mapping available in your deployer and DXA Web application for "cd_dynamic_conf"? Is your XML well formed? Also replace Domain="test-holidays.com” for publication 33 (extra space) for consistency.

Comment: yes, this is a problem from copy/pasting and changing real names. Our xml is well-formed

Answer (score 0):

The strategy is to iterate over all the publications in the file, then log is printing all the possible matches, but afterwards the correct publication is selected

2016-01-25 19:53:44,980 DEBUG [com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.localization.LocalizationFactoryImpl] (default task-2) createLocalization: [41] /

Comment: I did not quite understand! Is this your answer or an update to your question?